# "-eq" operator always rings true for string comparisons between double brackets

Tags: bash

For example:

```
A="T"
if [[ $A -eq "M" ]]; then
    echo "$A"
fi
```

this will always echo `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-eq` is meant for integer comparisons. And between `[[` and `]]`, if operands around `-eq` (and `-ne`, `-lt`, etc.) are not integers but valid variable names, bash assumes these are variables and tries to dereference them (recursively). In that same context, an unset/empty variable's value is considered to be zero; so, you're basically comparing 0 to 0 there. See this transcript:

```
$ unset A M T
$ A="T"
$ if [[ $A -eq "M" ]]; then
>     echo "$A"
> fi
T
$
$ T="1"
$ A="T"
$ if [[ $A -eq "M" ]]; then
>     echo "$A"
> fi
$
```

When `T` is assigned a number other than zero, it doesn't *ring true* anymore.

For further information, refer to:

- [Conditional Constructs § `[[..]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b),
- [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#:~:text=Shell%20variables%20are%20allowed,to%20be%20used%20in%20an%20expression.).